# Can the netduino board send and receive directly to and from my appharbor app?

Tags: appharbor, netduino

Hi i would like to send data from my netduino board directly to my app that is hosted on appharbor, I couldn't find any examples.  I may be asking the question wrongly, if so thanks for you patience. 
:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/01/16/http-request-class-for-the-.net-microframework.aspx) has resources on how to send http reqeusts from .NET Micro Framework apps. If you send JSON from the board, you can receive in an ASP.NET MVC 3 action on AppHarbor. There's an example on this question: [Receive JSON from external server, parse it and save it to local database with MVC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922206/receive-json-from-external-server-parse-it-and-save-it-to-local-database-with-m)

Comment: Hi frism, thank you for your answer, is there an example on how I get appharbor to accept the data from the device.

Comment: You can really do whatever you want on the AppHarbor side. I would send JSON from the board and receive it an ASP.NET MVC 3 action. There's an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922206/receive-json-from-external-server-parse-it-and-save-it-to-local-database-with-m

Answer (score 1):

http://netduinohacking.blogspot.com/ has a good example.

Comment: Its a good code base but it doesn't actually allow you to send a request directly, only a a response to an incoming request. +1